# In Spring, how do I POST to a URL using WebClient?

Tags: spring, http, post, webclient

Right now, I have a class `Message` representing a JSON object as so

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Message {

    @JsonProperty("@msgType")
    String msgType;
    @JsonProperty("@type")
    String type;
    String category;
    @Singular("characteristic") List<CharacteristicItem> characteristic;
    @Singular("receiver") List<ReceiverItem> receiver;
    Sender sender;

}
```

I would like to send an instance of the class Message as a JSON to remote URL `https:example.com/message`. How can I create a method that can POST to this URL with the JSON? Note, I am not creating a mapping, I just want to POST to URL and retrieve the HTTP response and convert to string. I'm thinking of using `WebClient`. Note, I am only interested in seeing if the response is 200, 400, etc., I don't need to handle the response JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `WebClient` you can write below code to post `JSON` data to URL and retrieve response status code.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
                     .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                        .build();
Message m = Message.builder().build();
Mono<HttpStatus> httpStatusMono = client.post().uri("/createMessage")
                                         .body(Mono.just(m), Message.class)
                                         .exchange().map(r -> r.statusCode());
// s.value() will give you response status code
httpStatusMono.subscribe(s -> s.value());
```

If you dont wan't to use `WebClient` another alternative is `RestTemplate`
below is the code to achieve the same thing with `RestTemplate`

```
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
ResponseExtractor<Integer> responseExtractor = clientHttpResponse -> {
    return Integer.valueOf(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().value());
};
Message m = Message.builder().build();
RequestCallback requestCallback = clientHttpRequest -> {
    objectMapper.writeValue(clientHttpRequest.getBody(), m);
};
Integer status = restTemplateBuilder.build()
                      .execute("https://example.com/createMessage",
                        HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
System.out.println(status);
```